# How to inject objects of the same class with different scopes?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld, jsr299

**In terms of simplicity and correctness, what is the best way to inject objects of the same class with different scopes?**

In a servlet I want to have injected objects of the same class with different scopes. 
Still don't know if going to use jsf.

- Simplicity: Making a `Qualifier` and a producer method for each scope is too much; making an interface, two classes and adding and alternative in `beans.xml` is also too much; having an `Address#isCurrent()` method doesn't make sense.
- Correctness: JSR299, 3.11 says: *The use of @Named as an injection point qualifier is not recommended.*  Still don't know why.
  Though using `@Named` at injection point works with `@ApplicationScoped` and
  `@RequestScoped` but not with `@SessionScoped`. See *named snippet* below.

In spring it is very easy:
**Spring snippet**

```xml
<bean id="currentAddress" class="xxx.Address" scope="session" />
<bean id="newAddress" class="xxx.Address" scope="request" />
<bean id="servlet" class="xxx.MyServlet">
 <property name="currentAddress" ref="currentAddress" />
 <property name="newAddress" ref="newAddress" />
</bean>
```

**named snippet**

```java
/* Address class */
@Produces @RequestScoped @Named(value="request")
 public Address getNewAddress(){
 return new Address();
}

@Produces @SessionScoped @Named(value="application")
 public Address getCurrentAddress(){
 return new Address();
}
/* Servlet */
@Inject @RequestScoped @Named("request")  private Address newAddress;
@Inject @ApplicationScoped @Named("application") private Address currentAddress;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  @nsfyn55 for pointing out that [good article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html), after reading the section  "The Right Way", I came up with what I think is the best way to achieve it in terms of simplicity and correctness.

So I am using only one interface for the qualifier annotation.

```java
/* Qualifier annotation */
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD,METHOD})
public @interface Scope {

 Type value();

 enum Type { REQUEST, SESSION, APPLICATION };
}


/* Address class */
@Produces @Scope(REQUEST) @RequestScoped
 public Address request() {
 return new Address();
}

@Produces @Scope(SESSION) @SessionScoped
 public Address session() {
 return new Address();
}

/* Servlet */
@Inject @Scope(REQUEST)
private Address newAddress;

@Inject @Scope(SESSION)
private Address currentAddress;
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the inclusion of this recommendation is the same reason one would prefer Enumeration over arbitrary strings for constants and that is because its not type-safe. You can easily mistype the name of the class and it would compile fine and fail at runtime. The recommendation is included because in most cases @named makes your application unnecessarily fragile when you have the ability force these constraints at compile time.

Here is a [good article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html) that outlines the reasons:

The preferred way to handle this situation is using @Qualifiers with enumerated values. Checkout the section entitled "String Qualifiers are Legacy" and "The Right Way" for the steps to handle this.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.
I can see the reasons to discourage the practice of @Named("string").

After reading the article you suggested I came with a new idea that I like more: having only one qualifier for both methods. I will try it later.

Comment: I edited that post I have noted to @Qualifier annotation as the preferred way to handle this.

Comment: Thank you, I just added my answer with snippet