# Inject HttpServletRequest into Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As I know per default are controllers in Spring MVC singletons. `HttpServletRequest` passed offen to the controller handler method. And its ok, while `HttpServletRequest` is request-scoped, but I see often `HttpServletRequest` gets `@Autowired` into the controller field, like this:

```
@Controller("CMSProductComponentController")
@RequestMapping(CMSProductComponentController.CONTROLLER_PATH)
public class CMSProductComponentController {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
}
```

Could be this a problem? And more general question: What happens if inject a reqeust-scoped component into a singleton?

Comment: Compile it, made an request and see! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373617/how-to-inject-objects-of-the-same-class-with-different-scopes it might be interesting for you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, for `HttpServletRequest` it will not be a problem and it shouldn't for other request scoped beans. Basically, Spring will generate a proxy `HttpServletRequest` that wraps some kind of `ObjectFactory` (`RequestObjectFactory` for `HttpServletRequest`) (YMMV) that knows how to retrieve the actual instance. When you use any of the methods of this proxy, they will delegate to that instance.

What's more, this is done lazily, so it won't fail at initialization. It will however fail if you try to use the bean when there is no request available (or if you haven't registered the `RequestScope`).

---

The following is in response to the comments and to clarify in general.

Regarding the `proxy-mode` attribute of [`@Scope`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) or the XML equivalent, the default *is* [`ScopedProxyMode.NO`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ScopedProxyMode.html#NO). However, as the javadoc states

> This proxy-mode **is not typically useful when used with a non-singleton
>   scoped instance**, which should favor the use of the INTERFACES or
>   TARGET_CLASS proxy-modes instead if it is to be used as a dependency.

With request scoped beans, this `proxy-mode` value **will not work**. You'll need to use `INTERFACES` OR `TARGET_CLASS` depending on the configuration you want.

With `scope` set to `request` (use the constant [`WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html#SCOPE_REQUEST)), Spring will use [`RequestScope`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestScope.html) which

> Relies on a thread-bound `RequestAttributes` instance, which can be
>   exported through `RequestContextListener`, `RequestContextFilter` or
>   `DispatcherServlet`.

Let's take this simple example

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES, value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public class RequestScopedBean {
    public void method() {}
}
...
@Autowired
private RequestScopedBean bean;
```

Spring will generate **two** bean definitions: one for your injected bean, a singleton, and one for the request scoped bean to be generated on each request.

From those bean definitions, Spring will initialize the singleton as a proxy with the types of your target class. In this example, that is `RequestScopedBean`. The proxy will contain the state it needs to produce or return the actual bean when it is needed, ie. when a method is called on the proxy. For example, when

```
bean.method();
```

is called.

This state is basically a reference to the underlying `BeanFactory` and the name of the request-scoped bean definition. It will use these two to generate a new bean and then call `method()` on that instance.

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) states

> The Spring IoC container manages not only the instantiation of your
>   objects (beans), but also the wiring up of collaborators (or
>   dependencies). **If you want to inject (for example) an HTTP request
>   scoped bean into another bean, you must inject an AOP proxy in place
>   of the scoped bean.** That is, you need to inject a proxy object that
>   exposes the same public interface as the scoped object but that can
>   also retrieve the real, target object from the relevant scope (for
>   example, an HTTP request) and delegate method calls onto the real
>   object.

All eagerly loaded request scoped beans, if implemented correctly, will be proxies. Similarly, request scoped beans that aren't eagerly loaded will either be proxies themselves or be loaded through a proxy. This will fail if there is no `HttpSerlvetRequest` bound to the current thread. Basically, a proxy is necessary somewhere in the bean dependency chain for request scoped beans.

Comment: Is this Spring `HttpServletRequest` proxy behavior documented anywhere?  Seems a fairly useful piece of functionality, but I haven't had luck tracking down any authoritative documentation.

Comment: @M.Justin I've been away from Spring MVC for a while. At a glance, it seems distributed across the Javadoc. Start with [`@RequestScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/RequestScope.html) annotation and the [`RequestScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestScope.html) class which handles it. That'll lead you to `RequestAttributes` which provides access to the current `HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if inject a reqeust-scoped component into a singleton?

Try it and you'll get a `BeanCreationException`¹ during application context initialization. The error message clearly explains why this doesn't happen with `HttpServletRequest`:

> Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a **scoped proxy** for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;

So obviously `HttpServletRequest` is a scoped proxy. If you want to use beans of smaller scopes in singletons they have to be proxies. The documentation elaborates about smaller scoped dependencies in [Scoped beans as dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection).

<sub>[1]: unless you didn't change the [default behaviour](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ScopedProxyMode.html#DEFAULT) for `proxyMode`, which is `NO` or try to inject it with `@Lazy`. The latter might result into a valid application context but might lead to request scoped beans acting like singletons (e.g. if a request scoped bean is injected into a singleton).</sub>