# How does the session scope of a bean work in a Spring MVC application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-session

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have a doubt about the **session scope** of a bean.

Into a project I have a `Cart` bean, this one:

```
@Component
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Cart {


    private Map<Product, Integer> contents = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<Product, Integer> getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return contents.keySet();
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product, int count) {

        if (contents.containsKey(product)) {
            contents.put(product, contents.get(product) + count);
        } 
        else {
            contents.put(product, count);
        }
    }


    public void removeProduct(Product product) {
        contents.remove(product);
    }

    public void clearCart() {
        contents.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return contents.toString();
    }

    public double getTotalCost() {
        double totalCost = 0;
        for (Product product : contents.keySet()) {
            totalCost += product.getPrice();
        }
        return totalCost;
    }

}
```

So this bean is automatically detected as component by the container and it is set as a **session bean** by:

```
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

So, from what I have understand it means that it is automatically created a single bean for each user session.

In my example the `Cart` class represent a shopping cart in which a logged user put the items that want buy. Does it mean that there exists a single `Cart` bean for each logged user section into the `HttpSession`? So this bean is into the session and the user can add or delete item from it. Is this interpretation right or am I missing something?

Another doubt is related to the `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` attribute. What exactly does that mean? Why is it applied to this bean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371335/spring-scoped-proxy-bean

See the accepted answer, best explanation so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So, from what I have understand it means that it is automatically
>   created a single bean for each user session.

The session bean will be created per user, but only when requested. In other words, if, for a given request, you don't actually need that bean, the container will not create it for you. It's, in a sense, "lazy".

The typical use is

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MySessionScopeBean myBean;
    // use it in handlers
}
```

Here, you're injecting a session scoped bean into a singleton scope bean. What Spring will do is inject a **proxy** bean, that, internally, will be able to generate a real `MySessionScopeBean` object per user and store it in the `HttpSession`.

The annotation attribute and value

```
proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS
```

defines how Spring will proxy your bean. In this case, it will proxy by retaining the target class. It will use CGLIB for this purpose. An alternative is `INTERFACES` where Spring uses JDK proxies. These do not retain the class type of the target bean, only its interfaces.

You can read more about proxies here:

- [What is the difference between JDK dynamic proxy and CGLib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664182/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-dynamic-proxy-and-cglib)

Here's a related post about the request scope:

- [Inject HttpServletRequest into Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674044/inject-httpservletrequest-into-controller)